# ambiguous column name timestamp

Tags: sqlite

I'm trying to select smoothed measurement data into another table:

```
INSERT INTO data (channel_id, timestamp, value) 
SELECT 1 AS channel_id, m1.timestamp*1000 AS timestamp, -IFNULL((m3.generation + 2*m1.generation + m2.generation)/4.0, 0) AS value
FROM meterreading m1
LEFT JOIN meterreading m2 ON (m1.timestamp = m2.timestamp-300) 
LEFT JOIN meterreading m3 ON (m1.timestamp = m3.timestamp+300)
```

This leads to

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: ambiguous column name: timestamp
```

Error goes away as soon as the INSERT part of the statement is removed.
As the INSERT() columns should be related to the target table and all other columns are aliased, I don't understand wahts wrong or how the problem could be fixed?

Comment: Just guessing: Could it be that the actual problem isn't column ambiguity but `timestamp` being a reserved keyword/identifier?

Comment: @Filburt No, `TIMESTAMP` is not an [SQLite keyword](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html).

Comment: Works for me. Which version?

Comment: @CL: Sqlite3 bundled with python 2.7.3. Running on SQLite 3.7.13 the error message changes:
Error: columns channel_id, timestamp are not unique

Comment: You don't need aliases for `INSERT ... SELECT ...`; only the number of columns must match. Is there anything you do not understand about the new error message?

Comment: @CL: I'm selecting 3 columns and want to insert 3 columns -> I don't get why the error message. The columns are apparently not ambigious without the INSERT, so what is the cause and how to fix it? I'm lost :(

Comment: You have an unique index on the `channel_id` and `timestamp` columns to prevent non-unique values.

Comment: doh: you're right of course- had to clean the table first. Now, python still shows the original error. My guess is that this is a problem that might have been fixed in sqlite but didn't make it into my python version yet. I'll give python3 a try...